# React Native: 'Could not find com.android.tools.build: gradle : 4.2.2.'

Tags: react-native, gradle

I'm creating React Native app and I got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '***'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2.
     Required by:
         project :
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (/Users/saman/Desktop/***/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/saman/Desktop/***/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/saman/Desktop/***/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/saman/Desktop/***/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

this is my grade.wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }

        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and this is my gradle.properties:

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: hey buddy, we are so badbakht, you have to use a ghandshekan or sth to pass this step

Comment: @MajidLotfinia thank you buddy, I used that ghandshekan and my problem has been solved...the problem occurred because of google's ban (error 403)